# How to find unrecognizable characters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data set, something like:

- 1 AAA
- 2 Asss, Inc
- 3 aÃ©roports de paris
- 4 AachenMÃ¼nchener
- 5 AachenMÃ¼nchener
- 6 Arco, Inc

I need to have result which contain records with only unrecognizable characters. 
In my example it'll be records N 3, 4, 5.

Is there any function or macro I can create to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly how do you define "unrecognizable" characters? Only digits and a-z,A-Z are OK, or are other characters acceptable?

Comment: To Tim Williams:  Yes, I'd prefer a-z A-Z and numbers 1-10 (any combination)

Comment: What about space or other punctuation?

Comment: To Tim Williams: I think I don't need to search for anything else... only something like Ã©, Ã¼, Ã perhaps, its foreign characters?  Also characters like "$" or "#"...

Comment: If you are copying this from a web page do you want non-breaking spaces converted to regular spaces or discarded altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Advanced Filter

With your Data in A6:A11  and a header added in A5

[image: Data]

Criteria Range A1:A2 and you can alter the character code; or add other character code ranges as additional criteria in the same column (eg. A3, A4)

```
A1:  <Leave Blank>
A2:  =SUMPRODUCT(--(CODE(MID(A6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A6))),1))>=128))>0
```

Filter Dialog Box:

[image: Filter Dialog]

Results:

[image: Results]

If you prefer VBA code, here is a macro that looks to see if there is any match with other than a desired character; you can see in the code where to add any desired characters to the list.  For starters, I have included letters, digits, space, and comma.  But you can add anything else you deem a recognizeable character.

=======================

```
Option Explicit
Sub BadChars()
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant
    Dim colRes As Collection
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long

    'Add allowed characters between the exclamation point and the closing bracket
    Const sPat As String = "*[!A-Za-z0-9, ]*"

vSrc = Range("A1").CurrentRegion


'Process data
Set colRes = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If vSrc(I, 1) Like sPat Then _
        colRes.Add vSrc(I, 1)
Next I

ReDim vRes(1 To colRes.Count, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To colRes.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = colRes(I)
Next I

Set rRes = Range("F1").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

================================

To **DELETE** the characters in the copy, try this code, which is similar to above, but uses regular expressions:

========================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub BadChars()
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant
    Dim colRes As Collection
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim I As Long

    'Add allowed characters between the exclamation point and the closing bracket
    Const sPat As String = "[^A-Z0-9, ]"

vSrc = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .ignorecase = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
End With

'Process data
Set colRes = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If RE.test(vSrc(I, 1)) = True Then _
            colRes.Add RE.Replace(vSrc(I, 1), "")
Next I

ReDim vRes(1 To colRes.Count, 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To colRes.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = colRes(I)
Next I

Set rRes = Range("F1").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

===============================

Results with deletions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way of doing it based on [unicode values](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html).  Right now I'm simply looking for code values between 32 and 122.  You can adjust this for more values that you want to include or exclude by changing the condition.

```
Sub findCharacters()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wks.Range("A1:A6")

    For Each cell In rng
        For Counter = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
            unicodeValue = AscW(Left(Mid(cell.Value, Counter), 1))
            If unicodeValue > 31 And unicodeValue > 123 Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

The result is highlighting the cell that contains characters outside of this range:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know, loops are ugly but this is just the first way to do it that came to mind.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try vba.... I don't think filter will work...I forgot to mention it's LARGE data set.... so - vba

Comment: To Portland Runner:  THANK YOU !!!!!!!!   VBA WORKED  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   Thanks soo much; It's VERY useful

Comment: It also would be wonderful if the vba would be able to delete these characters......

Answer (score 0):

It would be even more wonderful if this vba can also delete these characters...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean precisely, and an Answer is not how to address it.  IF you have additional requirements other than those stated in your original post, please set them out as a comment and add the precise requirements to your original post. Please be sure to follow the posting guidelines for setting out these additional requirements.  Also indicate how you tried to code this new problem, and where you are running into issues.

Comment: See the edit to my answer for what I think you mean by deleting the characters

Comment: Hi  Thank You!  Sorry for being unclear & slightly dummy. I meant to REPLACE unrecognizable characters with recognizable which is similar to the original word. Or replacing it with any recognizable - also fine.     Example:  Ma1/2323nchener=Maanchener

Comment: You will have to develop either a lookup table, so you know what to substitute, or definite rules that a computer can apply.  Once you do that, you should be able to code it easily.